# Mysql trigger with joins

Tags: mysql, sql, database, triggers

I have three MYSQL tables that all relate to each other as you can see below.

I'm currently storing the `dateofjob` twice because i do not know how to create table joins in a trigger. Currently i'm using this trigger on the specimen details table

```
CREATE TRIGGER `NewAge_update` BEFORE UPDATE ON `Speciemn_Details`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    SET NEW.Due_Date = DATE_ADD(NEW.CastDate,INTERVAL NEW.Age DAY);
END
```

And this is working perfectly, but i want to be able to remove the column `dateofjob` from the specimen details table and calculate the `duedate` from the Job_Details table to save myself from having double data.

I will have to join the `job_details.ID` with the `Test_Details.PARENTID` and the `Test_Details.TESTID` with the `specimen_details.TESTID`, I just don't know how to do this inside a trigger. any help would be appreciated greatly

I've attempted to  be as detailed as possible BUT If anymore information is required please ask me

Job_Details

```
 +----+-----------+
 | ID | dateofjob |
 +----+-----------+
 |  1 | 1/01/2015 |
 |  2 | 1/01/2016 |
 |  3 | 1/01/2017 |
 +----+-----------+
```

Test_Details

```
+----------+--------+--------------+
| ParentID | TestID | TestLocation |
+----------+--------+--------------+
|        2 |   2154 | Barn         |
|        2 |   2155 | Barn         |
|        1 |   8055 | Yard         |
+----------+--------+--------------+
```

Specimen_Details

```
+--------+----------+---------+-----------+-----------+
| TestID | Specimen | TestAge | dateofjob |  Duedate  |
+--------+----------+---------+-----------+-----------+
|   2154 | A        |       3 | 1/01/2016 | 4/01/2016 |
|   2154 | B        |       8 | 1/01/2016 | 9/01/2016 |
|   8055 | A        |       2 | 1/01/2015 | 3/01/2015 |
+--------+----------+---------+-----------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Joins inside trigger code really aren't any different from joins in any other procedural code, except that you can't query the triggering table and you instead have the `OLD` and `NEW` pseudorecords. If I've understood your description, you want to do something like

```
CREATE TRIGGER `NewAge_update` BEFORE UPDATE ON `Specimen_Details`
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    DECLARE jobdate DATE;
    SELECT dateofjob
      INTO jobdate
      FROM job_details j, test_details t
      WHERE j.ID = t.ParentID
        AND t.TestID = NEW.TestID;
    SET NEW.Duedate = DATE_ADD(jobdate, INTERVAL NEW.TestAge DAY);
  END;
```

(Don't forget that trigger bodies are *procedural,* so you don't have to do everything in a single statement.)

Comment: Thank you so much, I've been scratching my head over this for a few days.

Worked Perfectly!